# Prevent arg from showing MsgBox() if arg ends with ".lee" - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, args

I have program with `args` set as `Dim args As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`. I used `arg` as `String` in `args`. The program checks if `arg` ends with `".lee"` then continues. Else if the `arg` ends with `".txt"` it still proceeds to next steps. Else if `arg` is not meeting the requirements, it should pop up a `MsgBox`.

What the problem is even if a supported type file is executed, my program seems to show the error dialog box.

Code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim args As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
        For Each arg As String In args
            If arg.EndsWith(".lee") Then
                leeReader.RichTextBox1.LoadFile(arg, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
                TextBox1.Text = leeReader.RichTextBox1.Text
                Btn1.PerformClick()
            Else
                If arg.EndsWith(".txt") Then
                    leeReader.RichTextBox1.LoadFile(arg, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
                    TextBox1.Text = leeReader.RichTextBox1.Text
                    Btn1.PerformClick()
                Else
                    MsgBox("We don't recommend unsupported files")
                    Me.Close()
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

I tried to add `Exit Sub` but it wouldn't work.

Code after changes:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim args As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
        For Each arg As String In args
            If arg.EndsWith(".lee") Then
                leeReader.RichTextBox1.LoadFile(arg, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
                TextBox1.Text = leeReader.RichTextBox1.Text
                Btn1.PerformClick()
                Exit Sub
            Else
                If arg.EndsWith(".txt") Then
                    leeReader.RichTextBox1.LoadFile(arg, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
                    TextBox1.Text = leeReader.RichTextBox1.Text
                    Btn1.PerformClick()
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    MsgBox("We don't recommend unsupported files. Give it a try?")
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

If you know the solution/ If I am going wrong somewhere/ you need more help, please answer/ comment below.

Comment: Can you show a typical sample of the command line? Are you encountering spaces or something else? Show the 'arg' in your messagebox while you try work out what is causing your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping through all the command line arguments, but (from the docs)

> The first element is the executable file name, and the following zero
>   or more elements contain the remaining command-line arguments.

So you're always going to see the messagebox for the first argument. Try: `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1)`

Comment: I keep getting this unhandled Exception when I run the program:
 `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Lee Converter.exe`

`Additional information: Unable to cast object of type '<SkipIterator>d__30``1[System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'.`

Comment: It occurs on the following line:
`Dim args As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1)`

Comment: Well, yes, you'll need to do `.Skip(1).ToArray()` or just say:   `Dim args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`